# Rewriting a recursive function in perl so that it can be used in list context

Tags: perl, recursion

Consider the binary tree developed in [Moose::Cookbook::Basics::Recipe3](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-1.24/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Basics/Recipe3.pod)

To retrieve all nodes [in preorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), I could add the following subroutine to the BinaryTree package

```
sub pre_order {
  my ($self,$aref) = @_;

  push @$aref, $self->node;

  pre_order($self->left,$aref) if $self->has_left;
  pre_order($self->right,$aref) if $self->has_right;
}
```

The sub would have to be used like this:

```
my $btree = BinaryTree->new;
#add some nodes

#then later...
my @nodes_in_preorder;
$btree->pre_order(\@nodes_in_preorder);
```

How would i have to change the subroutine to be able to use syntax like the below:

```
my @nodes_in_preorder = $btree->pre_order();
```

in order to be able to do things like

```
for ($btree->pre_order()) { #bla bla }
```

later on.

Does this make sense, or am I being to pedantic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
sub pre_order {
  my $self = shift;
  return ($self->node,
    $self->has_left ? $self->left->pre_order : (),
    $self->has_right ? $self->right->pre_order : ());
}
```

Comment: Fantastic ! Thanks, that is even more elegant than i had hoped for :-)

Comment: Less efficient (which probably makes no meaningful difference except on huge trees).

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the caller:

```
for ( do { my @preorder; $btree->pre_order(\@preorder); @preorder } ) {
```

Or simply change the code like so:

```
sub pre_order {
    my ($self,$aref) = @_;

    push @$aref, $self->node;

    $self->left->pre_order($aref) if $self->has_left;
    $self->right->pre_order($aref) if $self->has_right;

    return @$aref if wantarray;
}
```

No need to pass an array reference to the outer call; one will be created automatically, so your code will Just Work (TM):

```
for ( $self->pre_order() ) {
```

Comment: first example could be `for (map {$btree->pre_order($_); @$_} []) {`, in the second example, it would be nice to get `$aref` back in scalar context

Comment: @Eric Strom: nice but error prone.  better to always return a reference if that may sometimes be needed.

Comment: The `$self->` isn't missing, it is left out on purpose. If you invoke e.g. `$self->pre_order($self->left,$aref)` then the first item in `@_` will again be the same `$self`; the next will be `$self->left` and only the third will be `$aref`. So this will result in deep recursion because you are calling `pre_order` on the same `$self` while also clobbering `$aref`. Try it.